# Rails Tutorial 11.4.1 - Extensions to the sample application exemplary repositories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org, reference-implementation

Do you have, or know of, Github repositories with implemented feature extensions suggested in [Section 11.4.1 of the Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec%3aextensions_to_the_sample_application) that you consider exemplary and use for reference?

Preferably extensions for the version 3.2 sample app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/kltcalamay/sample_app/compare/original-version...master

Comment: +1 Looks like a pretty good reference, so thanks for that.  It's for version 3.0 though, so *for now* I'll keep searching for a 3.2 version.  In case other's like me missed it on the Github repo page, the app is deployed [here](http://microblog.kennethcalamay.com).

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of old.  But I wasn't able to find anything else.  I'm a noob with Rails and even this solution I don't quite understand.

Comment: Hopefully more will be made in the future, but it seems you've found the only, and therefore best, one :-)